# illegal cookie attribute in svnedge

Tags: http, cookies

I am using Subversion Edge in dev mode. I am trying to replicate against a CTF server. When converting to replica mode, I get the following error.

```
2013-04-23 12:50:59,100 [27048996@qtp-15880435-5] DEBUG integration.CtfRemoteClientService  - ---Start of headers---
2013-04-23 12:50:59,100 [27048996@qtp-15880435-5] DEBUG integration.CtfRemoteClientService  - Date: Tue, 23 Apr 2013 07:21:20 GMT
2013-04-23 12:50:59,100 [27048996@qtp-15880435-5] DEBUG integration.CtfRemoteClientService  - Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
2013-04-23 12:50:59,101 [27048996@qtp-15880435-5] DEBUG integration.CtfRemoteClientService  - CtfUserName: nobody
2013-04-23 12:50:59,101 [27048996@qtp-15880435-5] DEBUG integration.CtfRemoteClientService  - Location: http://abc.example.com/sf/sfmain/do/myPage;jsessionid=uOtw2JGeCTy3sn1BSniWsDg4.tf
2013-04-23 12:50:59,101 [27048996@qtp-15880435-5] DEBUG integration.CtfRemoteClientService  - Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
2013-04-23 12:50:59,101 [27048996@qtp-15880435-5] DEBUG integration.CtfRemoteClientService  - Content-Length: 0
2013-04-23 12:50:59,101 [27048996@qtp-15880435-5] DEBUG integration.CtfRemoteClientService  - Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=uOtw2JGeCTy3sn1BSniWsDg4.tf; Path=/sf
2013-04-23 12:50:59,101 [27048996@qtp-15880435-5] DEBUG integration.CtfRemoteClientService  - Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=uOtw2JGeCTy3sn1BSniWsDg4.tf; Path=/sf; HttpOnly
2013-04-23 12:50:59,101 [27048996@qtp-15880435-5] DEBUG integration.CtfRemoteClientService  - Set-Cookie: sf_auth=uses7bfc94a1b3add70b1002263a&uOtw2JGeCTy3sn1BSniWsDg4.tf; Path=/
2013-04-23 12:50:59,101 [27048996@qtp-15880435-5] DEBUG integration.CtfRemoteClientService  - Set-Cookie: SoapOneTimeToken=15A425792DEA0ACBF19DC3F3050FC27B; Path=/
2013-04-23 12:50:59,101 [27048996@qtp-15880435-5] DEBUG integration.CtfRemoteClientService  - Cache-Control: max-age=0
2013-04-23 12:50:59,101 [27048996@qtp-15880435-5] DEBUG integration.CtfRemoteClientService  - Expires: Tue, 23 Apr 2013 07:21:20 GMT
2013-04-23 12:50:59,101 [27048996@qtp-15880435-5] DEBUG integration.CtfRemoteClientService  - Vary: User-Agent
2013-04-23 12:50:59,101 [27048996@qtp-15880435-5] DEBUG integration.CtfRemoteClientService  - Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=10000
2013-04-23 12:50:59,101 [27048996@qtp-15880435-5] DEBUG integration.CtfRemoteClientService  - Connection: Keep-Alive
2013-04-23 12:50:59,121 [27048996@qtp-15880435-5] DEBUG errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Resolving exception from handler [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController@1715d1]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal cookie attribute
```

Not sure what the problem is.. Help me on this..

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue is fixed in java1.7
Updating the java from 1.6 to 1.7 fixed the problem for me.

[Link to the bug tracked by java](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6790677)